# How do I make a geometric gradient background like this using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, background

How do I create a geometric gradient background like this?

[image]

I applied gaussian blur to an image with bright colors to use as a base. I also have a hexagon pattern if it's needed.

Thank you very much to anyone who can help me.

edit: I prefer PS but I'm open to AI answers as well.

Comment: If at all possible, I would seriously consider using Illustrator rather than Photoshop for this.

Comment: @Vincent I do have Illustrator but I haven't tried using it yet to create anything. I'm open to any answers using Illustrator though. I just prefer Photoshop since I have more experience using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck, there's an amazing little web app that does just this, with any kind of image:

http://damienclarke.me/code/mosaic-maker

You can see how it works, here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vO5AbU0O-P8

Create an image with the kind of colouring you want, then use the above app. Watch the video first, you'll see how it works, and then know what to create to get the gradient you want.